# Uploading a video to App Engine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, http-post

I want to upload a video to app engine (blob store) via android. Currently when running , nothing happens (only thread executing but I do get a warning when running :

```
 VFY: unable to resolve static field 2678 (INSTANCE) in   Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser;
```

Any ideas to solve this ?

Thanks !

Filepath for FileBody :

```
/storage/emulated/0/test/djfff_20140219.mp4
```

This is my JSP :

```
    <%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory" %>
    <%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService" %>

    <%
        BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    %>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Upload video</title>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor="FDF9FD">   
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> 
            <form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/uploadUrl") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table align="center">
             <th>Selecteer video
             <input type="text" name="foo">
                     <input type="file" name="myFile">
             </th>
             <tr>
             <td> <input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
             </tr>
        </table>        
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This is my thread in Android :

```
private static class uploadVideo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    String selectedPath;
    public uploadVideo(String selectedPath) {
        this.selectedPath = selectedPath;
        System.out.println(selectedPath);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.kinevub.appspot.com/video_upload.jsp");

        FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(selectedPath));

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("myFile", filebodyVideo);
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        try {
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to upload FROM the Android App to AppEngine or are you trying to Upload from the Android App to Your server which in turn uploads the file to AppEngine? Please clarify.

Comment: Uploading the file to App Engine (through a form -> JSP (located on app engine)) -> App Engine uploads the file to the blobstore

Comment: So you're attempting to upload the file from Android to your JSP form, which sends it to AppEngine? Does that sound correct?

Comment: The JSP is located on the App Engine. When this form has been submitted it's details go to a servlet (app engine) which saves the file to the blobstore